# Ionic Push Notifications with Ionic.cloud

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement the push notification service of Ionic (1) using the docs from official site (https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/), but i don't understand how can i retrieve, register and save the token on my Ionic App.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin installed with the  the correct configuration and register your application to **Ionic.io platform** with also the correct configuration (like describe in the official documentation).

So, in your `app.js`, you can write this :

```
    /* PUSH */
    //If cordova is installed 
    if(window.cordova){
       var push = new Ionic.Push({
          "debug": false,
          "onNotification": function(notification) {
             //Do something when you receive a notification
             console.log(notification);
          }
       });

       var callback = function(pushToken) {
          //Save the token specified to the device 
          //this token is saved in the Ionic.io database
          push.saveToken(pushToken.token);
       }

       //register you device to your app notification system
       push.register(callback);
   }
```

Then the **Ionic.io platform** allows you to send notifications easily to all the devices registered.

[image: The Ionic.io push interface]

Comment: Hi, thanks for support!
I have trying to insert in my app your solution but when I call the function that execute it, the console show this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAndroid' of undefined**

The function that i call is this:

`$scope.login = function(){
      var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
      var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
      if(window.cordova){
          //here your code
          //...
          //...
     }
}`

Comment: Hum it's really strange. If you have no error about the device information that means ionic.Platform is defined but the console says the exact opposite right after it. You maybe can try this `$ionicPlatform.is('android')` (ionic v1).

Comment: Hum ok ^^. What does the `ionic.Platform.device()` return ?